# Image ranker/sorter

Tags: windows, images

I'm looking for something that can as efficiently as possible help me sort a group of images based on my personal preference.

I would imagine what I'm looking for would look like something that uses pivot sort, prompting the user with two photos at a time asking for their preference, until the images have been sorted and ordered in order of preference.

I have too large of a photoset for me to want to try and do it all by hand and the closest I've been able to find is some digital photo albums allowing the user to rate a photo between one and five stars which is not close to what I am looking for (since I want a comprehensive ranking).

Not sure if there's anything like this, since it might be too niche of a need.

Answer (score 1):

You could try a pairwise comparison tool. I work for PollUnit which is offering such a voting type. See our short description here:

> In a Pairwise Comparison, multiple options are compared against each other. Voters choose their favorite from random pairs. PollUnit creates a relative ranking from the votes, helping to find the best option without having to compare all combinations.
>
> https://pollunit.com/en/pairwise-comparison

Normally several people vote and not just one. If you are voting alone, you should increase the number of rounds.

We utilize the ELO score, a system originally designed for chess ranking, to assess the relative strengths or preferences of images.

Answer (score 0):

You might be interested in charasort (https://github.com/execfera/charasort), a web-based tool that uses merge sort to compare images. It's intended for building sites that let end users rank video game and anime characters — it pairs each image with a corresponding name, then displays the names in order once the user has manually sorted them all. It's designed for someone to fork it, then substitute their own images instead, either from internet links (like imgur) or a designated img/ directory like [this fork uses](https://github.com/james7132/NepSort).

The main hurdles I can foresee are:

- Inputting images and their names requires editing a JavaScript file, which is a little annoying to do by hand. It might take a bit of programming knowledge if you have many hundreds of images and want to speed that up.
- By default it expects very small images. This can be changed in the CSS files but that also requires some effort.
- It does not actually do anything with the files themselves, like renaming them or moving them to different directories according to their order; it just gives you a sorted list of their names. This may be enough for your purposes, though.